# Amending Translation Values in CRM 2011 Outside of the Translation Files

Tags: localization, dynamics-crm-2011

I have received a requirement to amend the translations of the 'Add new..' and 'Add existing..' buttons in French. A typical default button is shown below:

[image: Example buttons with standard translations]

The desired new translations are essentially to remove the gender neutrality (if my rather poor school French is correct!). So rather than 'Ajouter un(e)' we have 'Ajouter un'.

Unfortunately these button labels are **not** included in the standard translations file (Settings -> Customisations -> Export Translations).

Are there any other options available? Given the nature of the requirement, I am happy to consider pretty much any kind of hack. CRM must be generating these values from somewhere, any ideas where they are hidden?



*Note: I profoundly disagree with this requirement for fairly obvious reasons and I am sure most people reading this question will as well. However, requirements are what they are and sometimes customers/clients just will not budge. This is one of those cases.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the labels for CRM Ribbon controls. See [Use Localized Labels with Ribbons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328323.aspx).
In order to make this work, you need to export the ribbon definitions and identify where these controls are defined.

You should be able to define a CustomAction to override the definition of the existing control but include the label text you want to have instead of the default label text. See [Define Custom Actions to Modify the Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334655.aspx).

If you are already experienced with customizing the ribbon this shouldn't be too hard, but there is a signifcant learning curve when it comes to customizing the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks for this - it sounds fine. I will take a look when I get to the office tomorrow.